# Implement Offset-based pagination using pothos-graphql

Tags: graphql, prisma

I'm trying to implement offset-based pagination using `pothos,@pothos/relay` and `prisma`,
I have `primsa` object implemented using pothos looks like this

```
builder.prismaObject("user", {
          fields: (t) => ({
            id: t.exposeID("id"),
            factories:t.relation("factories")
        }),
    });
```

and implemented query field to query the users with pagination

```
builder.queryField("user", (t) =>
  t.connection({
    type: "user" // this should refer to above created pothos/Prisma model,
    resolve: async (_parent, args) => {
      return await resolveOffsetConnection({ args }, async ({ limit, offset }) => {
        return await db.user.findMany({
          take:limit,
          skip:offset
        })
      });
    },
  })
);
```

to implment this i reffer to [this exmaple](https://pothos-graphql.dev/docs/plugins/relay).but it throws an error saying my `user` pothos/prisma type is not assignable

error message

```
Type '"user"' is not assignable to type 'OutputType<ExtendDefaultTypes<{ PrismaTypes: PrismaTypes; Scalars: { Date: { Input: Date; Output: Date; }; };  }>>'
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/hayes/pothos/discussions/729) is the solution I made with the help of pothos creator