# Custom database query/type in pothos-prisma-graphql backend?

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using the stack prisma -> pothos -> graphql on the backend. This is nice because it makes everything typesafe etc.

I have a table, 'projects', which I want to paginate but I don't know an effective way to do this in Pothos-Prisma.

I suppose, my question is two part:

- how do you create 'view-like' virtual types in pothos despite its type-enforcing?
- if this isn't the correct way to go about paginating 'projects', what is?

I found this post here (https://github.com/hayes/pothos/discussions/729) which suggested I use `builder.objectType("NewTypeName", ...)` to create a custom type. This custom type would include conveniences such as page details. However, when I try to do the same thing, I get:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectParam<ExtendDefaultTypes<{ Context: GraphQLContext; PrismaTypes: PrismaTypes; }>>'`

as a type error. To fix it, I have to change it to builder.objectType<any, any>(...). I don't actually know if the above 'fix' -- hack -- will actually compile because I have already wasted too much time trying hacky things to get this to work. If this is the correct way to do this, however, it would be good to know.

I understand that pothos is trying to be type safe, but I often want to create custom types, as one might do with SQL views that do not exist in the prisma schema. Is there a good way to do this?

(Additionally, I found this [Implement Offset-based pagination using pothos-graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74970579/implement-offset-based-pagination-using-pothos-graphql) post which simply linked to the other post I listed in this question.)